# JSF component - IN: pick file from server; OUT: file path only

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I need to find some very compact component which allows me:

- choose file in file system
- get its **absolute** path (or file itself)

I've tried:

- `<rich:fileUpload>` component, but it seems to be unnecessarily robust for such simple staff, and what's more, it can't return absolute path in RF4 (just file name) neither `File` object but `FileUpload` object
- `<input type="file"/>` but I'm not sure how to pass the **absolute** path of selected file to the bean (i'm able to pass just a name o file) - is it possible?
- `<p:fileUpload>` and `<t:inputFileUpload>` are also a bit problematic

**notes**:

- user always working directly on server (there are no clients) - `localhost` (the application is three tiers but for one user only)
- i'm using `richfaces 4`

What is the best or most compact practice for solving this?

**update** (partial solution)

```
<h:commandLink value="fire" action="#{bean.action}"/>
<input type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName"/>

public void action() {
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
}
```

But still without absolute path...

Comment: You want the path client side or the one of the uploaded file (once on server)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **fileUpload**'s *fileUploadListener* attribute. For example

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{managedBean.onFileUpload}"/>
```

If you are using RichFaces 3.*:

This requires implementation of a method in the managed bean, the signature of which must match `void onFileUpload(org.richfaces.event.UploadEvent event)`. By referencing the `org.richfaces.event.UploadEvent` object, you can retrieve the absolute path of the file. Like this:

```
public void onFileUpload(UploadEvent event) {
   //...
   File file = event.getFile();
   String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
   //...
}
```

If you are using Rich Faces 4.*:

This requires implementation of a method in the managed bean, the signature of which must match `void onFileUpload(org.richfaces.event.FileUploadEvent event)`. By referencing the `org.richfaces.event.FileUploadEvent` object, you can retrieve the absolute path of the file. Like this:

```
public void onFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
   //...
   File file = event.getUploadedFile();
   String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this `File file = event.getFile();` doesn't work for now

Comment: And UploadEvent is missing in RichFaces 4.x :-(

Comment: Oh, you should have said you're using RichFaces4 (or maybe I haven't read the question carefully). I'll update the answer.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.richfaces.request.UploadedFile25 cannot be cast to java.io.File` --- so I have to use `UploadedFile file = event.getUploadedFile();` which not consists `getAbsolutePath()` method :-(

Comment: can you try with the getName() method ?